# Brick drilling in close distance to another hole?

Tags: drill, brick

I am about to install a samll kids coat hanger, however it seems I will need to drill another hole about 1 cm from the existing one (brick wall). Is it at all possible or should I look for another location?

Comment: I avoid drilling brick; drill in mortar if possible.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - Sorry I might have misspoken. The house is 100% bricks, but the bit I'm dirlling is actually plastered bricks. I'm not sure how thick the plaster layer is but I assume no more than 2cm meaning I do drill into the brick. It's a bit trick to find pointing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angle the new hole away from the other by about 15 degrees. Put it on the correct side so that you can angle it towards the center of the brick.

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand correctly, start driling at the point I need a screw but at ~15deg to go away from the inital hole? I can't tell where the middle of the brick is as it is covered with plaster layer.

Comment: @BroiSatse - If you go straight in you risk cracking the brick there, joining the two holes and making them both useless. Pick a side and hope for the best. If you never see any red brick dust, use a longer screw than recommended, because you're likely into mortar (which is not ideal for *masonry* screws, but not a huge crime for coat hangers). Add the thickness of the plaster to the length of the recommended screw.